# Centering TableLayout rows using Java Code

Tags: android, tablelayout

I would to create a TableLayout and center its content.
I write this piece of code:

```
TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(this);
tl.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

TableRow firstRow = new TableRow(this);
TableRow secondRow = new TableRow(this);
```

But It doesn't work. Rows are centered but only vertically... How can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

```
TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(this);
tl.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL));

TableRow firstRow = new TableRow(this);
TableRow secondRow = new TableRow(this);

firstRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER));
secondRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set a LayoutParams for the TableLayout and set the gravity on it:

```
tl.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL) );
```

Comment: with your line of code my layout content is on the upper corner of display, on the left :)

Comment: Please change both LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT to LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT

Comment: The rows in a TableLayout require the parent's LayoutParams. Try to set the LayoutParams to your rows: firstRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER));

Comment: I edited code in my answer. With this code I obtain: http://postimage.org/image/upz8slxsx/ :(